# Configure maven task-segment in pom file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

My project currently utilize Ant build, to build SQL i use below target:

```
<target name="build.update_database">
    <artifact:mvn pom="${basedir}/../module-database/pom.xml">
        <arg value="clean"/>
        <arg value="compile"/>
        <arg value="liquibase:updateSQL"/>
    </artifact:mvn>
</target>
```

Now i want to move Maven, how can i configure the steps 'clean', 'compile', 'liquibase:updateSQL' in pom.xml.

The pom.xml is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything else. You already have the pom.xml file. The [Ant Mvn Task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html) executes Maven commands. It was like executing `mvn clean compile liquidbase:updateSQL` in the command line.